# Manage bot's webhooks with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So here's my problem:
I'm trying to create a discord bot for the RP with discord.py, and I can create webhooks with,
but not get the URL of the webhooks created by this bot.
Do you know how to do it?

[webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDmXo.png)
(I can't copy the url manually ://)

Comment: Do some searching on how to implement your requirement. Please refer when and how to ask questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little foggy on what youre asking but if you are asking what I think,I suggest you manage webhook urls via the program like so

```py
        #put what you want in these variables for the webook to send
        msgvar=""#message
        usernamevar=""#username
        avatarvar=""#profile pic

        if len(await ctx.channel.webhooks())==0:#check if there is already a webhook
          await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="mywebhook")#if not create a webhook

        #Actually send the webhook
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            sessionhook=(await ctx.channel.webhooks())[0] #get the first channel webhook 
            webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(sessionhook.url, adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))#create webhook from url
            #send
            await webhook.send(content=msgvar, username=usernamevar, avatar_url=avatarvar)
            await session.close()#exit out
```